# Xcode 4 - Debug Area no longer shows my console output (NSLog)

Tags: xcode4

My NSLog messages no longer show up in my Debug Area. Anyone have an idea how the could have happened?

I can hit command-7 to bring of a list of logs in the left pane, select the latest one and view it in my editor window, but it is extremely annoying compared to having the console output in the debug area.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/42826227/3063226

Comment: This is so dang silly. Apple hates developers.

Comment: check this if you are facing this issue in Xcode 15 https://stackoverflow.com/a/78218511/1844851

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Not sure but may be you have clicked on one of the three buttons at the top right corner of the debug area that are used to either show only variables view, only the console or both.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't click it for the heck of it, but that certainly didn't look to me like it would have helped :)

Comment: I'm guessing those buttons aren't there any more in newer versions of XCode?

Comment: there are only two now

Answer (score 57):

I had the same issue. Below are fix for this :

1. You *console may be hidden*. Press `Show the console` button present in right corner (blue coloured when console is open).

   [image: Screenshot 1]
2. You may be displaying *Debugger or Target output*. Select `All Output` (Checkmark is displayed when selected).

[image: Screenshot 2]

3. a. Open `Xcode preference` (shortcut: cmd + ,).

   b. Select `Behaviours` tab from pop-up.

   c. From the `Build` sections select `Succeeds`.

   d. Enable `Show debugger with Current Views`.

   e. Select `Console View` from the drop-down list.

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 4]

Comment: You saved my life. I foolish i was.

Comment: Such a lifesaver! I've attempted to fix this before, but never found your answer until now. The All Output thing was the solution.  I guess debugger is about things that the **debugger output** prints for you through `po` `p`, etc. **Target output** is simply things that you print through the actual code itself. To test this, simply change the output and you'll see

Answer (score 33):

if you want to display Debug area always, then follow these steps:

- Goto XCode > Preferences > Behaviors > Succeeds >
- Check checkbox of `Show  tab named`
- Type DEBUG in the textbox next to `Show  tab named`
- select `separate window` in dropdown next to Textbox
- Now click checkbox before `debugger with` and select `Console View` in the dropdown

[image]

Now when you will run our app, console window will popout itself.

And shortcut key for this is `command+shift+y`

Comment: There is no such thing as '**Show debugger with**' in Xcode 7.3.

Comment: No, it is available in XCode 7.3. Still updating my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is there. Check this one. http://s33.postimg.org/kezllrg0v/exmple.png **Show** is separated from **Debugger With**. click on the checkbox to enable **Show**

Comment: Yes, please do as he instructed.  I can see the debugger output on console.

Comment: Also, the Answer #4 below ok.

Answer (score 11):

For me, the answer is to 'activate console'

Go to `view -> Debug Area -> Activate Console`

Answer (score 9):

You have a few choices:

- In the menus, select View -> Show Debug Area.
- In the View selection controller in the upper right, enable the bottom view (the one in the middle).
- If you'd like this to show automatically, go to Preferences -> Behaviors. Select "Run Starts" and enable "Show" Debug Area.

Comment: View --> Debug Area --> Activate Console  worked for me

Answer (score 9):

For Xcode 8

I set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to `disable` to hide crazy logging message in simulator. But it will also hide NSLog output on my iPhone SE device (print function in swift still works).
Remove the environment variable makes NSLog work again.

Comment: This was driving me insane for 2 hours! Apple always has to "add" something to "help" us.

Comment: Go to "Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments" and make sure the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` environment variable is not set

Answer (score 5):

I had an iOS universal app that would show debugger output for the iPhone version, but not for the iPad version.

I looked into editing the schemes ( <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> ) and the iPad scheme had a different debugger than the iPhone scheme. I changed the iPad scheme's debugger to match the iPhone's (from LLDB ---> GDB)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Make Sure that in your **Debugger Area >> Debugger Bar** you have Selected **ALL OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Took me a while to figure this out... Here's a screenshot of Xcode 6.1.1. Make sure you have chosen `All output` at `1` and activated the output pane in `2`. Somehow the output pane suddenly was gone for me and I just didn't see the icons at the bottom for like 2 hours.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just confirm that you have Xcode open with similar rights as you have the ownership of the files you are trying to build/run and also make sure you have same rights to the build directory. I noticed Xcode won't show any debug output if rights were mismatched. I figured this after facing so much harassment. When this happened, utilities>console was still showing logs. I used that as a workaround.

Mine is: Xcode 4.2 Build 4D199 on OS X 10.7.2

Answer (score 3):

For me, "Debug Executable" in Scheme Settings (**Product-->Scheme-->Edit Scheme: Run**) had been unchecked.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On an 12.1 Xcode version you can do either:

Option 1: View > Debug Area > Activate Console

Option 2: Shift + cmd + c (to activate console)

Option 3: (if your console is already activated) Shift + cmd + y

Here is a picture for you:

[picture that shows menus and options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdcXz.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have anything displaying in the logs, the log view will unselect itself and not display itself.  You could add a `printf` and verify this.