# NSLog not printing to console

Tags: nslog

I have an Xcode project I've been working on for months. I've never had a problem with NSLog, but after upgrading to Xcode 4.2 nothing will log to the console. I even tried throwing this in viewDidLoad:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Can anyone hear me?");
```

And nothing. Is anyone else having this problem or know a solution?

Comment: Check if this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34743750/1753005

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing. The console got deactivated somehow and I was actually watching the variables window. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd></kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> did the trick.

Many thanks to Robert King on this thread:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/565880#565880

Comment: I had the same thing, but it wasn't after the upgrade. I've been using it for awhile now. I have no clue how it happened though...strange. Also, (if this is indeed a bug) I thought I should note that I'm running Xcode 4.3.2

Comment: Holy cow. This happened to me too. I spent 2 days on this until I saw the 'solution' here. Good lord.

Comment: My console is open, it's set to show all output, and my NSLogs still aren't showing up.

Comment: @bugloaf you fixed it?I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Holy cow ! Happens now after updating OS (XCOde 8.2.1) Thanks !

Comment: where is this Apple sign key in keyboard ?

Answer (score 77):

This is a bug of Xcode8 + iOS10, we can solve it in this way:

When on **simulator**, add the Name `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and the Value
Variables `disable` and check it (Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Environment).
[image]

When on **device**, only add `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and check it（don't add the Value). You'll see the NSLog in the Xcode8 Console.
[image]

Answer (score 12):

In iOS10, a lot of system logging is displayed on the console. This can be disabled by including the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disabled in the Run Arguments for your scheme

However for iOS10, NSLog messages will not be displayed anymore. 
In lower iOS versions the messages will still be displayed. So maybe for most test cases you can use a lower iOS version.

Otherwise you can include a Swift function which prints (print function) your text, this is working okay in iOS10.

Tested on iOS10.0.2 and iOS9.3

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me.  Is this a bug that has been reported?

Comment: I believe so, because Apple has fixed this in the new Beta.

Answer (score 10):

My issue is that I have **Debugger Output** selected.  Once I changed it to either **All output** or **target output** NSLogs appear fine.

In case this confuses you its on the left of the Debug area.

Comment: Dayum ... you know how long this confused me? I couldn't figure out for the life of me why I couldn't see this output.

Comment: Where is this option?

Comment: @TalhaAhmadKhan sorry its been too long since I answered this and have not coded in IOS for some time. Hopefully, someone else may be able to provide the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
The trick is to search and remove the below mentioned line from the project.

```
  #define NSLog(...)
```

Search the entire project and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this, so here's another thing to check.

-> Make sure you don't have anything typed in the Filter field below the Log Output.  So, in my case I was searching for a term in the logger and forgot to delete the searched terms out of the Filter text field.  DOH!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I'd accidentally severed the referencing outlet from App Delegate (delegate - file's owner).

Answer (score 0):

This similar issue was observed after upgrade to Xcode 15.0.1 for macOS. NSLog was not printing to console. The solution to this issue that worked for me is as mentioned below. Refer to https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/2023/10/5.html , https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/742594 for more info.

1. Under Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Run->Arguments, add an
   environment variable with key "IDELogRedirectionPolicy" & value
   "oslogToStdio"
2. Under Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Run->Options, set
   the console to "Xcode" or "Terminal"