# NSLog not logging output in console

Tags: xcode6, nslog

This issue is driving me crazy since last few days. In my project I have several NSLog statements that were working fine until recently.

I have tried Command+option+C to make sure my console is not disabled as shown in this answer here:[NSLog not printing to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856508/nslog-not-printing-to-console#7863491)

- I can see NSLog outputs in other new project that I create.

My question is, could it be something that I might have changed accidentally that has disabled logging NSLog statements/

I am on Xcode 6.3.2.