# NSLog for Console window

Tags: nslog

I just upgraded to Xcode 7 and I can no long use the NSLog statement to show messages for debugging?  NSLog(@"I am at the start of the loop");  This used to work and now I can't even write the statement in the code, it gives me a "expected parameter declarator"? What am I missing?  I researched this and can't find anything saying it's changed.  One day it worked and now it doesn't.  I can find it in my older projects and it still works within those older projects.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Shift` + `` + `C` (equivalent to View >  Debug Area > Activate Console)

[Credit to this original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7863491/3167331)