# Inhereted project.. NSLog does not print to console

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I was given a project file and after opening it up I have noticed NSLog does not print to the console.

I've tried shift + command + c and that didn't work.

The strange thing is if I open any other project they print to console just fine still.  However this one does not.  Is this an xcode setting?  if so why is it only this one project that is effected?  and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: Check the prefix.pch, there can be overdefined.

Comment: where is the prefix.pch located?

Comment: you can use search field in the bottom of project navigator to filter shown files by name

Comment: ah ok, no.. there isn't anything defined for NSLog in prefix.pch

Comment: @JesseDurham: It is under the Supporting files. The exact name is "PROJECTNAME"-Prefix.pch

Comment: @Dave I found the file.  No changes to NSLog are in it.

Comment: try to modify or check your debugger LLDB / GDB (from... Product / Edit Scheme..) .. like here.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11973686/1702413

Answer (score 7):

***1) newer attempt to help***

Make sure you're printing out *everything* from NSLog.  There's a toggle you can set in the console window:

[image: All Output should be selected in the Console output popup]

***2) original attempt to help***

Try doing a "`#undef NSLog`" at the top part of your code and see if "`NSLog`" works again.

If so, then Dave is correct... you need to search around your code to see where "`NSLog`" has been redefined.

Comment: #undef NSLog made no change

Comment: if you do a search through your source, can you see any place where "`NSLog`" might be getting adjusted?

Comment: I did a search and got nothing other than general NSLog prints, and asked the person originally working on the project if they had changed anything and they said no.

Comment: I've tried both the All Output as well as only the Debugger Output ( I read somewhere else before asking this question that changing it to Debugger Only would fix the issue).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just experienced a case where NSLog suddenly stopped displaying. I don't know what actually caused it but, in my case, a simple restart of Xcode made the problem go away. Just posting in case it helps somebody else.