# NSLog not getting printed in the console area while debugging on device?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, nslog

I am facing a weird issue.NSLog statements are not getting printed to the console when i am debugging my application using the device.I even pulled the log files using the organizer even there they are not having the logs. When i debug it in the Simulator they are getting logged to the console properly.

I tried using both the GD debugger and lldb debugger.. That did not work

Any ideas what might be causing the issue??

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318342/what-happens-to-nslog-info-when-running-on-a-device

Comment: Here is another that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697161/xcode-4-debug-area-no-longer-shows-my-console-output-nslog

Comment: Sometimes people use macros that can override `NSLog`.   You might try putting a breakpoint before one of the `NSLog` statements and seeing where the statement executes when on the device.   Occasionally, I've seen this done in header files for third-party (open source or commercial) libraries and the symptom is that your logs stop working under some build conditions.

Comment: If pulling the console logs with Organizer doesn't show anything it's pretty much certain that the NSLog is being NO-OPed.  Highlight NSLog in one of your modules and do RMB-Jump to Definition and see where that takes you.  The default is NSObjCRuntime.h.