# NSLog does NOT print out in new project running on the connected device, Xcode 6.1 or higher

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslog

My colleagues and I found the situation in new project created from Xcode 6.1 or higher, in which NSLog would NOT print itself out in the console when the project is running on the connected device, while it would print out when the identical project is running on the simulator.

edit: For testing I created a brand-new single-view application project with no dependency (SDK, pod files, headers, macros, etc.) installed, then add one line of NSLog in viewDidLoad method of the main view controller. The problem remained.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Does ASL output on the device as you would expect? Does the NSLog behavior replicate on multiple devices? Are they managed devices?

Comment: Duplicate (but unanswered) question.  Check the comments.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547636/nslog-not-getting-printed-in-the-console-area-while-debugging-on-device

Comment: Are you looking at the console in Xcode or on the device's console?

Comment: @Rob The console in Xcode

Comment: First, I'd check the device console and make sure you're seeing it there (go to "Devices" on Xcode's "Window" menu; you may have to expand the bottom half of the device window to see the live console there). If you don't, you might have something completely suppressing NSLog (e.g. some include header redefined the macros of something like that). Second, do you have any non-standard "scheme" settings? For example, if you uncheck "debug executable" you won't see the live console messages in Xcode's console.

Comment: @Rob Thanks again for replying. Unfortunately none of these is the case. For testing I created a brand-new single-view application project with no dependency (SDK, pod files, headers, macros, etc.) installed, then add one line of NSLog in viewDidLoad method of the main view controller. The problem remained.