# NSLog not working when "wait for executable to be launched" is set

Tags: ios, debugging

I am just exploring debugging as per the subject line. I am noting that while this works easily enough, the NSLog's are not outputting, but breaks do get hit. This is not helping ;) .. I don't see any obvious options in the edit scheme window.

This is to test pushes, but firstly i am just manually firing up the app to ensure the process works (with waiting for the app to manually start etc)..

Thanks for any tips..

Comment: Breakpoints work. Learn how to use them for logging :)

Comment: On simulator breakpoints doesn't work, but on my iPhone 6s no problem. Another option could be using log system such as SwiftyBeaver

Comment: I just ran into this issue. I changed my prints to breakpoint based logs and the logs show up on the debugger console.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you let the process start normally, then the logs will be hooked up to ASL already.  The debugger doesn't have a good way to reroute this connection after the fact.  You will have to look in the Device Console for the logs.  In Xcode 6, select Windows->Devices, then there's a little disclosure widget at the bottom of the content window that will reveal the Device console.

Comment: awesome Jim, i just learned something new and very valuable, much obliged. The wonders of Xcode never cease.

Comment: Plus one for mentioning that illusive disclousure button

Comment: It's in the same place in the Devices window.  It's easy to miss the little disclosure widget (it will show up in the lower left hand corner of the content pane once you've selected your device from the Device list.)  But it is still there.

Comment: this console doesnt seem to include NSLog out.. only system stuff ?

Comment: @bobmoff it does, but it only logs things happening after you open the device logs

Comment: although the log window doesn't seem expandable, is it? it's so small T_T

Comment: If you are using Swift, print() will not show up in the logs, you will need to use NSLog. I also have found that the best way to see your messages is do a search for your app name in the console. Then, change any to Process, and you will only see your NSLogs (or ones that show up in the xcode console window).

Answer (score 44):

**Use breakpoints to log whatever You want**

Right click on breakpoint -> Edit Breakpoint

[image]

- Check "Automatically continue after evaluating options" to make sure app won't stop at break
- Add Action(s) to log info You need

[image]

Comment: I see the original tone of this msg was altered, thank you, but this comment misses the point of the original question, which was answered a year ago. But thank you regardless..

Comment: Good thing about printing with breakpoints is that You don't need to recompile project. You can add/remove breakpoints on a run

Comment: @PauliusVindzigelskis The bad thing about printing with breakpoints is that it is much slower so any debugging of time sensitive things does not go well.