# How to Debug an app after it is terminated and then reopened in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, swift4.2

I usually do debugging with support of print() method at which shows on Xcode logs as long as it is not terminated. However I have some conditions that I need to test in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of AppDelegate when the app's been terminated and then reopened. By "reopened" I mean by clicking on the app on simulator/iphone instead of running it from Xcode again. Sadly after termination print logs do not show. Any other way I could do it? Thanks!

Comment: this was really helpfull! in my terms of Swift usage! thankyou

Answer (score 20):

Click on the options near the Appname on the upper-left corner of Xcode.

Click on **Edit Scheme** -> Check the **Wait for executable to launch** option and run as you usually do. Happy Coding :) .

[image]

Comment: I dont see that. I wish you added an image to make things clearer.

Answer (score 4):

- Check "Wait for executable to launch" as @vishnu_146 mentioned.
- CMD + R to run the app (first launch)
- Double press Home and kill the app
- **CMD + R** to run the app again (I tested that run without build will fresh launch the app).
- App open with previous status. Can hit break points, but could not print logs. Reason: [NSLog not working when "wait for executable to be launched" is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950525/nslog-not-working-when-wait-for-executable-to-be-launched-is-set)

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 4.2**,

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let fileName = "\(Date()).log"
let logFilePath = (documentsDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
freopen(logFilePath.cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii)!, "a+", stderr)
```

> Just add this block of code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the app delegate file and it will create a log file in app document directory on iPhone which logs all console log events. You need to import this file from `iTunes` to see all console events.
>
> Note: In the .plist file make sure that Application supports `iTunes file sharing` exists and is set to `YES` so that you can access through `iTunes`.
>
> To get Logfiles: Launch `iTunes`, after your device has connected
>   select Apps - select your App - in Augmentnt Document you will get your
>   file. You can then save it to your disk

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing logs through "NSLog". On Xcode, go to "Devices and Simulators" and select your device. All the NSLogs will be visible there at the bottom.