# Xcode 8 (Swift) No print output in Console

Tags: swift, xcode, logging, console, output

The question in the topic: Why no print output in Console using Simulator? 
Is it disabled or this is a bug?

Comment: In the debug area, hit the right half-square. show the console

Comment: also try   View --> Debug Area --> Activate Console

Comment: Thank you Nazrul Hasan! Activate Console command helps.
Also I customized Sheme: I added environment variable: "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE" with "disable" value. I thought it hides only os notifications.

Comment: Also, to activate console with keyboard shortcut `Shift + Command ⌘ + C` - Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: Sometimes you have to restart the Xcode even if the console is activated. So quite the Xcode and reopen the project. It worked for me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try with this way

> View --> Debug Area --> Activate Console

Comment: That wasn't me, but basically the question is about a different, much more complex problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828670/xcode-doesnt-write-anything-to-output-console

Comment: bless your soul haha, spent way too long being confused about this.

Answer (score 11):

same answer as @Nazmul Hasan, but with an image to help others.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that you could not type `print("the data you want to print")` in normal class with no type.

You need to type this code in general `viewController`, such as `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`.