# print not working in Xcode 8.3.1?

Tags: printing, xcode8

Is it just me and my colleagues or is `print` broken in Xcode 8.3.1? I'm not seeing anything in the xcode interface after upgrading from 8.3.0, both in the simulator and on a device. Breakpoints are hit correctly and I've double checked everything like described in [Xcode doesn't write anything to output console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19828670/2054629)

Comment: Hi, currently have same problem, have manage to fix it?

Comment: Yep I downloaded 8.3.0 again and stopped using 8.3.1...