# Cordova app suddenly has no console log in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, console.log

My Cordova app has been output console.log just fine in Console of Xcode. Then suddenly one day (not sure what happened), it just shows blank. I followed the instructions here but nothing works [Xcode 4 - Debug Area no longer shows my console output (NSLog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697161/xcode-4-debug-area-no-longer-shows-my-console-output-nslog)

Here are what I have:

[image]

This always shows but BLANK:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

I tried an old codebase and no console log either. So this looks like Xcode configuration specific. Something messed up randomly and automatically.

Comment: I recently read that it is possible to use Safari's devtools to connect to/debug a remote device based on its webview over usb as well (much the same as you can with chrome/android) - I don't mention it as a possible solution so much as a possible additional diagnostic.

Comment: I am using Cordova plugin so I am not sure if Safari can output that especially it must have access the device feature as an app (not a website)

Comment: Would seem reasonable re: the plugin output. I just looked again. It is in the early access version of [this book](http://www.manning.com/camden/) , which I would encourage you to consider buying. But it says that if you enable web inspector in Settings>Safari>Advanced, even hybrid app webviers will show up in your connected safari devtools. I have not tested it, so I cannot confirm, but the author is no hack.

Comment: I just tested it and it works. But my intention is to look in Xcode console (just for the convenience). I would not prefer to open Safari and go thru the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the deployment to device AND start may take up to a minute. If you open the app manually right after it deployed, it is a different instance and no debug available in Xcode. You have to wait for Xcode to run the app itself to show console info.