# Xcode does not print any console log

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cordova

I have a project that integrated with cordova, when I debug my Xcode IDE does not print anything to console log.
I have tried with App code it's the same

Best,

Comment: And when you don't Debug it prints something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova app suddenly has no console log in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179186/cordova-app-suddenly-has-no-console-log-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [Console Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console#cordova-plugin-console) to your Cordova project.

```
cordova plugin add cordoba-plugin-console
cordova build ios
```